# Strange errors when running MinGW compiler under Cygwin environment

Tags: cygwin, mingw-w64

I'm "cross-compiling" Zlib with MinGW under Cygwin environment

If I run the compiler under Cygwin shell, I get a lot of strange errors:

```
$ /bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe  -O3 -Wall -c -o adler32.o adler32.c
/tmp/cc5e9THF.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc5e9THF.s:7: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
/tmp/cc5e9THF.s:8: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
/tmp/cc5e9THF.s:9: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
...
```

However, when I run the same from the Windows shell, it seems to work

```
"c:\cygwin64\bin\i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe"  -O3 -Wall -c -o adler32.o adler32.c
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: try `/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`

Comment: @matzeri The miracle! It works! But... how?

Comment: the GCC compiler is referring some of its own components with a relative position to the main executable. 2 levels down if I remember correctly.